# Invention based on arduino and its modules

Tags: arduino

If I create something that has arduino and its modules, for example [RCWL-0516](https://github.com/jdesbonnet/RCWL-0516#patents) which is protected(maybe?) by patents, the only unique thing will be the product body with custom made water pump, can I make this product commercial?

Long story short: I noticed that every arduino module has lots of patents, so does it mean that for commercial project I have to invent my own modules to sell my final product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really two questions. First is whether you can market a product using available modules which have patent protection. Second is whether you can receive a patent for the final product. As to the first question, the module's patent protection might be on a specific component contained within the module. The manufacturer wants to sell modules so I would contact the manufacturer and find out what, if any, limitations there are on the use of their modules in your product. My guess is they would be happy to allow this and you would want to negotiate volume licensing anyways.

With respect to whether your product is patentable, this has to do whether it meets the requirements of patentability which includes novelty (inventive step), non-obviousness and utility. There is no way for us to answer that question without knowing more about your product and you can't disclose that before filing an application. I will say that if you are using off the shelf components in ways that they are intended to be used and there isn't some unexpected cleverness involved then there isn't much chance for a patent.

Comment: Thank you! One question more - what if  I use patent protected modules manufactured in China, which are probably replicas and is being sold all over China.

Comment: It really depends on the patents. If you are planning to sell in the US than a US patent is enforceable no matter where the device is manufactured. If you are planning to sell in China, then you need to figure out if equivalent patents exist in China.

Answer (score 2):

There is a concept called "patent exhaustion". If you buy something from a party that is licensed to every patent embedded in the product, then "using" the item would not, per-se, be an infringement of patents fully embodied in the item itself, as shipped. The specific use you put it to and how it is connected to other components could infringe some patent not directly related to the purchased item.